# Differentiate with respect to $x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

Differentiate with respect to $x$

$$f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x^2}-4+\dfrac{8}{x^{2/3}}$$

Solution(is it correct having difficulties with the fractions):

$$=x^{2/3}-4+8x^{-2/3}$$

$$=\dfrac{2}{3}x^{-1/3} - \dfrac{16}{3}x^{-5/3}$$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Are you asking for verification?

Comment: I dont understand what has been written

Comment: I am having a lot of trouble parsing the expressions here. Where does the square-root end?  Or are you trying to make a cube root?

Comment: @ncmathsadist Same!

Comment: Edited the post.@ncmathsadist its suppose to be a cube root and it ends at $x^2$. Having trouble with the formatting.

Comment: @user112498 Please confirm that I have correctly edited what you wrote.. also, I didn't remove the equal signs you used in your expressions to remind you that equality is different than a thread connecting thoughts. In your last two equalities, the first is supposed to be $f(x)$ and the second is the potential $f'(x)$ you're asking for justification of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is:

> Differentiate the following function with respect to $x$:
>   $$f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x^2} - 4 + \frac{8}{x^{2/3}}$$

Then the answer is indeed:
$$
f'(x) = \frac{2}{3}x^{-1/3} - \frac{16}{3}x^{-5/3}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The problem follows easily by using the power trick: $(x^n)' = nx^{n-1} $